# Shared value from test case in devops

Tags: c#, .net, devops

I'm trying to access the shared value from a test case in devops . I can access them if they are not shared
When non shared I got a nice parameter set :

```
<NewDataSet><xs:schema id='NewDataSet' xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:msdata='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata'><xs:element name='NewDataSet' msdata:IsDataSet='true' msdata:Locale=''><xs:complexType> <xs:choice minOccurs='0' maxOccurs = 'unbounded'><xs:element name='Table1'><xs:complexType><xs:sequence><xs:element name='Parameter1' type='xs:string' minOccurs='0' /><xs:element name='Parameter2' type='xs:string' minOccurs='0' /><xs:element name='Parameter3' type='xs:string' minOccurs='0' /></xs:sequence></xs:complexType></xs:element></xs:choice></xs:complexType></xs:element></xs:schema><Table1><Parameter1>1</Parameter1><Parameter2>2</Parameter2><Parameter3>3</Parameter3></Table1></NewDataSet>
```

but when I use shared parameter I get this

```
{"parameterMap":[{"localParamName":"Parameter1","sharedParameterName":"sharedValue1","sharedParameterDataSetId":1065},{"localParamName":"Parameter2","sharedParameterName":"sharedValue2","sharedParameterDataSetId":1065},{"localParamName":"Parameter3","sharedParameterName":"sharedValue3","sharedParameterDataSetId":1065}],"sharedParameterDataSetIds":[1065],"rowMappingType":0}
```

There is the code I'm using to get the data

```cs
private DataTable GetTableItemsFromTestCase(int workItemId)
        {
            var accountUri = new Uri("xxxxxxxxxx");     // Account URL, for example: https://fabrikam.visualstudio.com                
            var personalAccessToken = "xxxxxxxxx";  // See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/pats?view=vsts              

              // Create a connection to the account
              var connection = new VssConnection(accountUri, new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, personalAccessToken));

            // Get an instance of the work item tracking client
            var witClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();

            IEnumerable<XElement> descendants = new List<XElement>();
            var dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                // Get the specified work item
                var workitem = witClient.GetWorkItemAsync(workItemId).Result;

                var itemParams = workitem.Fields["Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.Parameters"];
                var itemParamsElement = XElement.Parse((string)itemParams);

                var paramDataSource = workitem.Fields["Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.LocalDataSource"];
                var xElement = XElement.Parse(paramDataSource.ToString());

                //Assuming we have a table named "Table1" in the workitem
                descendants = xElement.Descendants("Table1");

                foreach (var xe in itemParamsElement.Descendants("param"))
                {
                    var name = xe.Attribute("name").Value;
                    dt.Columns.Add(name, typeof(string));
                }
                foreach (var descendant in descendants)
                {
                    var r = dt.NewRow();
                    foreach (var xe in descendant.Descendants())
                    {
                        r[xe.Name.LocalName] = xe.Value;
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(r);
                }
            }
            catch (AggregateException aex)
            {
                VssServiceException vssex = aex.InnerException as VssServiceException;
                if (vssex != null)
                {
                    return new DataTable();  //log error
                }
            }
            return dt;
            
        }
```

It's a dot.net 6 project and it crash on shared value at :

```
 var xElement = XElement.Parse(paramDataSource.ToString());
```

The object I get from the request don't seem to contain any value :
[Shared value object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlr4N.png)

I've seek in the object to find the value , tried to find more doc on the net or example but it was unsuccessful .

Comment: Find out you need to make a new request for each parameter to fetch the corresponding work item and then unscramble the DataTable to fit each value with corresponding parameter